# Running spark application doesn't show up on spark history server

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am creating a long running spark application. After spark session has been created and application starts to run, I am not able to see it after click on the "show incomplete applications" on the spark history server. However, If I force my application to close, I can see it under the "completed applications" page.

I have spark parameters configured correctly on both client and server, as follow: 
spark.eventLog.enabled=true

spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://10.18.51.117:8020/history/ (a hdfs path on my spark history server)

I also configured the same on server side. So configuration shouldn't be a concern (since completed applications can also show up after I force my application to stop).

Do you guys have any thoughts on this behavior??

I look at the hdfs files on spark history server, I see a very small size .inprogress file associated with my running application (close to empty, see the picture below). It seems that the results get flushed to the file only when the application stops, which is not ideal for my long running application...Is there any way or parameters we can tweak to force flushing the log?

[Very small size .inprogress file shown on hdfs during application is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogksa.jpg)

Comment: That behavior is consistent with my experience as well. Is there any reason you can't watch the UI provided by the driver program itself? It's located at `http://<driver>:4040/` by default usually.

Comment: @TravisHegner I tried to use spark web ui with the 4040 port to check status during execution, but somehow it always give me a "HTTP ERROR 500" error message when running on a spark cluster. If I switch to local mode (single node), the web UI starts to work. Do you encounter that as well?

Comment: Which cluster manager are you using (Yarn, Spark-Standalone, Mesos)?

Comment: @TravisHegner I am using Yarn and deploy mode is client

Comment: In that case, the driver UI actually proxies through your yarn resource manager. If you look closely, you are being redirected by your driver program to your resource manager, and your 500 error is coming from there. This will typically happen of some networking issue (no route, firewall, etc.) is preventing your resource manager from accessing your driver program at port 4040.